# Keep checkbox state depending on its own state and another checkbox

Tags: html

Maybe this is easy, and I just can't see the tree for the forest, but I need some help on this one… ;-)

It's bit hard to explain in English but here we go. You may have to read it a few times to understand, as the "check" will come up a lot :-)

I have 2 checkboxes on a page.

If checkbox1 is unchecked, then checkbox2 should work as normal. So the user can check and/or uncheck it and save it. 
But if checkbox1 is checked, then checkbox2 should somehow keep its state.

So if checkbox2 is checked prior to checkbox1 is checked, then if the user tries to uncheck checkbox2 it should keep being checked.

And if checkbox2 is unchecked prior to checkbox1 is checked, then it should keep being unchecked.

How do I do this the best way?

Comment: i guess you will need javascript here, trying it on a fiddle

Comment: If the second checkbox is ticked then just disable the first checkbox.

Comment: Nope can't disable the first one, as it is a sales system, and the first one is used to stop price changes

Comment: But I found the solution I just needed this this.checked=!this.checked;

Comment: You can edit your own post to provide extra details. For example, you appear to be using js in addition to html, and it seems that there are extra requirements, such as not wanting to use disabled states (which would be user friendly, as they indicate that attempting to change state is futile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after I asked the question yesterday, I found the solution my self.
I needed to type `this.checked=!this.checked;` in onclick or onchange.

I know its a bit against best practice, that a checkbox that can't be changed isn't disabled, but we evaluated that it would confuse the user more, than the solution we choose.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible in plain html. Html checkboxes work independently of each other. However, it is relatively simple adding JavaScript, and there are several ways to handle it. This is a straightforward one:

```js
let one=document.getElementById("one");
let two=document.getElementById("two");
one.onchange = (e) => two.disabled = ! two.disabled;
```

```html
<input id="one" type="checkbox" name="one" value="1">1
<input id="two" type="checkbox" name="two" value="2">2
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a workaround with javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/gui3_/xf9rjanw/7/

or in plain html :

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check1">
<label>checkbox 1</label>
<br/>

<input type="checkbox" id="check2">
<label>checkbox 2</label>
<br/>

<script>
document.querySelector("#check1")
  .addEventListener("click", event=>{
    let check2 = document.querySelector("#check2")
    check2.disabled = !check2.disabled;
  });
</script>
```